# Change absolute positioning in Canvas from code

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating my own usercontrol where I have a Canvas which will hold Hexagons.

I'm now at the stage where I'm adding the function AddItem, and since I don't want the hexagons to overlap I obviously want to use the Canvas' positioning methods. But how do I access them from "normal" code?

I have a Path object `hexagon` which holds the hexagon-data and I want to add it to my canvas aka `container`

So how do I change the positioning from c# code?

I know that in XAML my path looks like this when inside the Canvas (please notice Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top) , you'll have to scroll a bit..

```
<Canvas x:Name="Container" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Path d:LayoutOverrides="None" d:LastTangent="0,0" Stroke="White" Fill="#343434" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Data="M8.660254,0 L17.320508,5 17.320508,15 8.660254,20 0,15 0,5 8.660254,0 z"/>
    <Path d:LayoutOverrides="None" d:LastTangent="0,0" Stroke="White" Fill="#343434" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Data="M8.660254,0 L17.320508,5 17.320508,15 8.660254,20 0,15 0,5 8.660254,0 z" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="37.5"/>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method

```
   Path myPath = ....; // obtain your path here
   Canvas.SetLeft(myPath,25);
   Canvas.SetTop(myPath,25);
```